# Function System.bytescopy

Tags: api, actionscript, haxe

I have been searching for this function and haven't found any reference to what it does, so I would like to know if anyone of you could tell me what it receives and the functionality.

The function Im copying is this: `System.bytescopy(buffer, cutsize*8, buffer, 0, (bufend-cutsize)*8);` but I dont know what it does and what it receives.

I have to copy this function (from haxe) to actionscript code cause I'm fixing a code that may help me to develop what I need. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.bytescopy` isn't Haxe's native function. Maybe you are referring to [this](https://github.com/francois2metz/WavPlayer/blob/master/System.hx).